# C# reload singleton cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, singleton

I need some directions here.
I have the following key/value cache:

```
public class Cache<TKey, TValue> : ICache<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _internalCache;
    private readonly object _syncLock = new object();

    public Cache()
    {
        _internalCache = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_syncLock) {
               //...
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_syncLock) {
               //...
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> GetAll()
    {
        lock (_syncLock) {
            return _internalCache.Values;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            return _internalCache.ContainsKey(key);
        }
    }

}
```

The cache above is used by a singleton wrapper:

```
 public class ActivityCache : ICache<string, Activity> 
 {
    private readonly ICache<string, Activity> _cache = new Cache<string, Activity>();

    private static readonly ActivityCache _instance = new ActivityCache();

    // http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html
    static ActivityCache()
    {
    }

    ActivityCache()
    {
    }

    public static ActivityCache Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public Activity this[string activityUrl]
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activityUrl))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return _cache[activityUrl];
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(activityUrl))
            {
                return;
            }

            _cache[activityUrl] = value;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Activity> GetAll()
    {
        return _cache.GetAll();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _cache.ContainsKey(key);
    }
}
```

This is working fine (I haven't noticed/heard of any errors... yet :) ).

But now I have a problem. I need to reload the cache with new key/values.

**Question 1.)** Can I implement a "safe" reload method that reloads the cache (the Dictionary in the Cache class) ?

E.g:

```
    public void Reload(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> values)
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            _internalCache.Clear();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> value in values)
            {

                /* Problems can (will) occur if another 
                   thread is calling the GetAll method... */
                _internalCache[value.Key] = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question 2.)** Should I use some IoC container or some other library instead?

Thanks!

**Note:** I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: Two comments: 1. If you have more read activity than write activity, you might consider using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` in place of `lock()` so that readers don't block other readers. 2. Why not just surround `GetAll()` with a lock as well?

Comment: 1.) Thanks, haven't heard of ReaderWriterLockSlim before. I'm going to check it out! 2.) Yeah, why not. Of course it should be a lock there as well... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should lock around GetAll as well.

You could use a double buffer type technique to make the reload less painful :

```
public void Reload(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> values)
{
    cache = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> value in values)
    {
        cache[value.Key] = value.Value;
    }

    lock (_syncLock)
    {
        _internalCache = cache;
    }
}
```

This will work providing you don't mind readers accessing potentially out of date information whilst you call reload.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer! I will definitely use the double buffer type technique. I don't mind if readers accessing out of date information while I'm calling reload. The only thing I don't want is that a reader gets a empty result back when the cache reloads. If I have understand this correctly, we can get an empty result back with your solution aswell?

Comment: If the value is in the old cache as well as the new cache, there is no reason why the reader should get an empty result.

Comment: If the value is not in the old cache, but in the new cache, they will get an empty result up to the point where you enter the lock when assigning the new cache.

Answer (score 3):

use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), then you wont have to deal with Synchronization.

Also, you dont want to reload all the cache items as well. instead you want to do staggering, load the cache objects in the key/value store on demand.

You can use timestamp or some versioning for that. if you reload the data per each key/value pair then you wont have to lock the whole collection.

I really recommend you to use ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` is awesome, but sadly unavailable in .NET 3.5, which is the OP is using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too bad I can't use .NET 4 :/ Do you have any example of a timestamp/version implementation?